# Ruby on Rails error while trying to redirect user after post data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I learn RoR by Getting Started Guide.

when i post data from form to Articles controller and redirect client to new article post i got error: undefined method 'article_url' (screenshoot https://s3.amazonaws.com/fvd-data/notes/117968/1423727915-CZTLAm/screen.png) code on github https://github.com/vmanyushin/rails_getting_started/blob/master/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb

I understant why this error occurs but how to fix it? if you look at the example from guide, this code should work.

Comment: Did you generate this with scaffold? I do not see other corresponding actions in your code. suppose the redirect shall lead you to the 'show' action, you need it to exist in under your controller.

Comment: no, i use rails g controller articles.

Comment: Your code seems to ok. Try run rails c on console and see if you have article in db or not. For this run Article.all. In my understanding data is not saving properly and sue to this reason you are getting this error.

Comment: data saved i check this from console....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

https://github.com/vmanyushin/rails_getting_started/blob/master/config/routes.rb#L2

This should be `resources :articles`

Note the plural on resources.

Answer (score -1):

for `redirect_to @article` to work your controller has to provide `show` action, as explained in the next section of the tutorial: [showing an article section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#showing-articles).

Comment: if redirect_to @article work property i got error like not finding show action....